# Apache Solr query not matching indexed content

Tags: database, solr

I am trying to pass a string of Japanese characters to an Apache Solr query. The string in question is `'製品'`.

When a search is passed without any arguments, it brings up all of the indexed information, including all of the documents that have this particular string in them, however when this parameter is passed in as `q=製品`, only one of the items is displayed.

Furthermore, when I have the query `fq=ss_language:ja&q=製品` **three** items are shown.

What would cause this peculiar behavior? The field in question where I am searching for this string is indexed, and my assumption is that it should bring up all documents with this string inside of them.

Here's the debug information:

```
<lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">製品</str>
<str name="querystring">製品</str>
<str name="parsedquery">+DisjunctionMaxQuery((content:製品)~0.01)</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">+(content:製品)~0.01</str>
<lst name="explain">
<str name="4gceoe/node/12782">
0.41303736 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(content:製品 in 80), product of: 1.4142135 = tf(termFreq(content:製品)=2) 5.3405533 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=307) 0.0546875 = fieldNorm(field=content, doc=80)
</str>
<str name="4gceoe/node/12768">
0.33378458 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(content:製品 in 66), product of: 1.0 = tf(termFreq(content:製品)=1) 5.3405533 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=307) 0.0625 = fieldNorm(field=content, doc=66)
</str>
<str name="4gceoe/node/12748">
0.2529327 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(content:製品 in 46), product of: 3.4641016 = tf(termFreq(content:製品)=12) 5.3405533 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=307) 0.013671875 = fieldNorm(field=content, doc=46)
</str>
</lst>
<str name="QParser">ExtendedDismaxQParser</str>
<null name="altquerystring"/>
<null name="boostfuncs"/>
<arr name="filter_queries">
<str>ss_language:ja</str>
</arr>
<arr name="parsed_filter_queries">
<str>ss_language:ja</str>
</arr>
<lst name="timing">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
<lst name="prepare">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="process">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
<lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
```

I'm sorta lost here, everything seems like it should work based on the documentation I've been reading.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the Japanese characters as UFT-16 using `%unnnn`, where nnnn is the hex Unicode for the char?

Comment: I would just put these escaped characters in the query string?